# PyGtk3, Catching single click event when button is single clicked

Tags: python, gtk3

I created `Gtk.VBox` container with `numbox = Gtk.VBox(spacing = 10)` line and I added too many widgets and button widgets into it. but when I click one times on any button widgets `numbox.connect("button-press-event", print_widget_prop)` code line not working. but when I click two or three times on any button, this code line working. why when I single click on buttons, this code line not working ?

example

```
from Gtk3Modules import * # this code line imports Gtk, Gdk, ... module

def do_anything(wid, event):
    print("clicked", event.get_click_count()[1], "times")


w = Gtk.Window(title="_Simple_Window_")
w.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)

evbox = Gtk.EventBox()
evbox.connect("button-press-event", do_anything)
w.add(evbox)

vb = Gtk.VBox()
evbox.add(vb)

lb = Gtk.Label("I am a label")
vb.add(lb)

btn = Gtk.Button("I am a button\nWhen You Single Click me do_anything function not work !")
vb.add(btn)

w.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Could you post your complete code? Or at least a [minimum, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: okey I will do thanks.

Comment: @theGtknerd, I did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something I never saw before. However, changing

```
evbox.connect("button-press-event", do_anything)
```

to

```
evbox.connect("button-release-event", do_anything)
```

does work for single clicks (for me anyway).

Comment: Thanks but this answer don't solve exactly my problem. if there is a another solution with "button-press-event", I want to know it. but if there is no another solution, I have to use this your solution.

Comment: can you give me your e-mail ? we can talk from there because you know PyGtk3 well. I want to talk with you about PyGtk3 and ask some questions.

Comment: @Nomad Could you explain why you need `button-press-event` and not `button-release-event`?

Comment: @Nomad I do give out my email, after I trust you. Let's continue on StackOverflow for now.

Comment: I wondered. perhaps there is a way with "button-press-event" to solve it. because this way fit for me. but I can solve it with your solution. Thanks

Comment: I very very want to learn PyGtk3 and I learned too many things. so I want to talk you from skype, etc ... because you know well. so what can I do to you trust me ?

Comment: @Nomad Three things I should mention: I don't use IM clients (Skype), you can build up trust posting good questions on StackOverflow, I check StackOverflow every day for Gtk questions.

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to @theGtkNerd answer.

This may be a bug. In fact, his answer to your other question where he suggest wrapping the button inside an Gtk.EventBox and then use the method `set_above_child` does the trick.

Anyway, my complement is that your method `do_anything` is not complete. In fact you need to return True or False:

```
def do_anything(wid, event):
    print("clicked", event.get_click_count()[1], "times")
    return False
```

This happens because the `button-press-event` callback returns a boolean to indicate if the signal should propagate to the parent widgets.

As an example, if you set a callback to the `btn` `button-press-event` event and then return true, you won't receive any single, double or third click events. This happens because by returning True it will indicate that the signal shouldn't propagate further along it's parents, up to the toplevel widget:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk # this code line imports Gtk, Gdk, ... module

def do_anything(wid, event):
    print "clicked ", event.get_click_count()[1], "times"
    return False
def do_button(wid, event):
    print "button clicked"
    return True 

w = Gtk.Window(title="_Simple_Window_")
w.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)

evbox = Gtk.EventBox()
evbox.connect("button-press-event", do_anything)
w.add(evbox)

vb = Gtk.VBox()
evbox.add(vb)

lb = Gtk.Label("I am a label")
vb.add(lb)

btn = Gtk.Button("I am a button\nWhen You Single Click me do_anything function not work !")
btn.connect("button-press-event", do_button)
vb.add(btn)

w.show_all()

#Gdk.set_show_events (True)

Gtk.main()
```

If you test the above code, you'll find that the events on the button won't propagate to the EventBox.

What this means?

Well, it seems that the `button-press-event` for a single isolated press is not being propagated. If you try a "double click" it will propagate with a count of 2 and three consecutive clicks will also propagate the signal.

It seems to be a bug but more details are needed, eg, digging the gtk source code to find the reason.

Comment: thanks ver much. I thought this. but I can't connect the signals to too many buttons in the EventBox. but this can be good solution.